# Any private/public API's for getting WIFI signal strength (RSSI) for iOS7 or 8

Tags: ios, ios7, wifi, xcode6, rssi

Hello my app needs to retrieve current wifi signal strength for iOS 7 devices and above. What I have found so far..

- Can get SSID and BSSID from CaptiveNetwork api/framework but **not signal strength**
- From my understanding Apple80211 is outdated and doesn't work with iOS 7 and above. MobileWifi.framework is an alternative that apparently works but a jailbreak is needed (I need non jailbreak).

So can anyone help me here? And please don't point me at other stackoverflow questions unless they provide me with a solution, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172387/how-to-measure-wifi-dbm-strength-on-iphone-x-ios-swift

Answer (score 0):

There are methods in iOS 7 and earlier that support direct access to RSSI; however, these seem to be deprecated in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Apple's (admittedly beta) documentation was wrong.  You need to use the protocol, CBPeripheralDelegate.

method def:

```
    override func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didReadRSSI RSSI: NSNumber, error: NSError?) {
        <#code#>
}
```

You call the peripheral's -readRSSI: method and it will callback to the above function, where you can extract the value from the `NSNumber` param.

Comment: CBPeripheralDelegate is for Bluetooth Smart and not for wifi.

Comment: This is true; however, iOS manages waking and sleeping the radios of the device, and it's lower energy than wifi.  In other words, it will accomplish the same thing as using wifi.