# How to measure WiFi dBm strength on iPhone X iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, wifi, iphone-x, dbm

I am looking for ways to get the raw signal of the wifi, the dBm on iPhone X phones, but can only find how to get the `numberOfActiveBars` from: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167577/using-private-api-to-read-wifi-rssi-value/48083845#48083845)

Trying @Mosbash answer, getting a crash.

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)` Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var hotspot: NEHotspotNetwork!

  func viewDidLoad() {
   ....
   hotspot = NEHotspotNetwork()
  }

  func record() {
    hotspot.setConfidence(.high) /// <- Crash
    print(hotspot.signalStrength) /// <- Crash if above line is commented out
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use signalStrength from NEHotspotNetwork as described here 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotnetwork/1618923-signalstrength

> When the Hotspot Helper app is asked to evaluate the  a network or
>   filter the Wi-Fi scan list, it  annotates the NEHotspotNetwork object
>   via the  setConfidence: method.

Here is the formula to convert Wifi Signal Strength Percentage to RSSI dBm:

```
quality = 2 * (dBm + 100)  where dBm: [-100 to -50]

dBm = (quality / 2) - 100  where quality: [0 to 100]
```

See this answer for more details:
[How to convert Wifi signal strength from Quality (percent) to RSSI (dBm)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797920/how-to-convert-wifi-signal-strength-from-quality-percent-to-rssi-dbm)

Comment: this gives you the value that lies within the range 0.0 (weak/no signal) to 1.0 (strong signal). This is not dBm, which ranges between around -20 to -90

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I tried to set the HotSpot helper but getting a crash that the phone is not using Metal. Any idea?

Comment: can you share your code and the crash stack trace please ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask permission from Apple and create entitlement.

Comment: Anyone who is wondering about "Apple Permission", please refer to Apple documentation:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/hotspot_helper#overview